# How do i apply a default font to all Text() elements in the app using Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I need to apply a common font to all the Text() used in my entire app. Currently i am applying it manually to each text using a style or font as follows. How can i specify this as a global theme for the app? In normal xml layouts, i was using a custom TextView widget to achieve this.

```
    Text(
            text = stringResource(id = R.string.userName),
            style = typography.h2,
            fontSize = 20.sp,
        )
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Jetpack Compose supports theming and a uniform font can be applied by specifying a custom font in app theme. Steps to do this are as follows.

###### Copy your custom font to res/font directory ex: helvetica_nue.ttf

[image]

###### Create a Kotlin file (Type.kt) and add your Font family object here. Specify the defaultFontFamily as your custom font. If you wish to perform some additional customization you may add your styles to body1 typography, as this is the default typography used for all Text() unless specified.

```
private val myCustomFont = FontFamily(
    Font(R.font.helvetica_nue),
)


val Typography = Typography(
    defaultFontFamily = myCustomFont,
)
```

###### Create a Kotiln file (Theme.kt or any name) and declare you app theme

```
@Composable
fun MyApplicationTheme(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    MaterialTheme(
        typography = Typography,
    )
}
```

###### In your activity/fragment, wrap your apps main Composable within this theme

```
 MyApplicationTheme {
            NewsDetailScreen()
        }
```

Now your app will display text in the specified font wherever the theme is applied.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/themes/material#typography

> If you want to use the same typeface throughout, specify the defaultFontFamily parameter and omit the fontFamily of any TextStyle elements:

Comment: This solution works for Material 2. Unfortunately, the parameter defaultFontFamily is not available in Material 3 https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material2-material3#typography:~:text=Note%3A%20Unlike%20the%20M2%20Typography%20class%2C%20the%20M3%20Typography%20class%20doesn%E2%80%99t%20currently%20include%20a%20defaultFontFamily%20parameter.%20You%E2%80%99ll%20need%20to%20use%20the%20fontFamily%20parameter%20in%20each%20of%20the%20individual%20TextStyles%20instead.

Comment: @ZakariaBoukaddouss for M3 check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76383549/2263329

Comment: @MahmudulHasanShohag, it looks like a good alternative to defaultFontFamily in M3.

Comment: my Typography doesn't have any defaultFontFamily

Answer (score 11):

You can use `typography` parameter in `MaterialTheme` to specify a default font.

In Material2 you can use `defaultFontFamily` parameter to specify a default font as shown by @Ajith. But the parameter is removed in Material3 (Material Design 3).

> Note: Unlike the M2 Typography class, the M3 Typography class doesn’t
> currently include a `defaultFontFamily` parameter. You’ll need to use
> the `fontFamily` parameter in each of the individual TextStyles instead.
> ([Source](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material3#typography))

But you can do the followings for Material3. Here is an example of setting the default font-family in M3:

```kotlin
// Type.kt

import androidx.compose.material3.Typography
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.Font
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import com.example.exampleapp.R

// Declare the font families
object AppFont {
    val TitilliumWeb = FontFamily(
        Font(R.font.titillium_web_regular),
        Font(R.font.titillium_web_italic, style = FontStyle.Italic),
        Font(R.font.titillium_web_medium, FontWeight.Medium),
        Font(R.font.titillium_web_medium_italic, FontWeight.Medium, style = FontStyle.Italic),
        Font(R.font.titillium_web_bold, FontWeight.Bold),
        Font(R.font.titillium_web_bold_italic, FontWeight.Bold, style = FontStyle.Italic)
    )
}

private val defaultTypography = Typography()
val Typography = Typography(
    displayLarge = defaultTypography.displayLarge.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),
    displayMedium = defaultTypography.displayMedium.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),
    displaySmall = defaultTypography.displaySmall.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),

    headlineLarge = defaultTypography.headlineLarge.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),
    headlineMedium = defaultTypography.headlineMedium.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),
    headlineSmall = defaultTypography.headlineSmall.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),

    titleLarge = defaultTypography.titleLarge.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),
    titleMedium = defaultTypography.titleMedium.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),
    titleSmall = defaultTypography.titleSmall.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),

    bodyLarge = defaultTypography.bodyLarge.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),
    bodyMedium = defaultTypography.bodyMedium.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),
    bodySmall = defaultTypography.bodySmall.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),

    labelLarge = defaultTypography.labelLarge.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),
    labelMedium = defaultTypography.labelMedium.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),
    labelSmall = defaultTypography.labelSmall.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb)
)
```

```kotlin
// Theme.kt

import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable

@Composable
fun AppTheme(
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    MaterialTheme(
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
}
```

Example for an individual component:

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import com.example.exampleapp.theme.AppFont

@Composable
fun ExampleScreen() {
    Text(
        text = "Hello World!", 
        fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One similar approach would be to first create custom implementation over Text composable, lets call it CustomText.
Then for your use case, you can write wrappers over most used text styles, for eg

```
@Composable
TextH2(text : String)  {
 //call your own wrapper over framework Text composable
  CustomText(text = text, typography = h2)
}
```

To make things simpler you can wrap font resource, weight and size together and then create specific implementation of this class
for e.g

```
val h2 = CustomTypography(font = R.font.your-ttf-file, fontSize = 20.sp, fontWeight = Medium)
```

Above styling data is handled inside one single composable, which in our case is CustomText.

Answer (score 0):

As the answer for Material 3 here is setting for each style the font separately, I'd like to propose another way. I know it's also not the best solution, but it might be the better solution until Material 3 provides better support to set a global font.

This snippet is based on the default project out of Android Studio:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        PlaygroundTheme {
            // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme

            CompositionLocalProvider(
                LocalTextStyle provides LocalTextStyle.current.merge(
                    TextStyle(fontFamily = FontFamily(
                        Font(R.font.rubik))
                    )
                )
            ) {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Greeting("Hello Android!")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Pay special attention to the ***CompositionLocalProvider*** where you can override the style with another local style, just that in this case the style is applied to all elements within the CompositionLocalProvider.